# Can not print sub directory inside a directory using Files.walkFileTree java nio

Tags: java, file, io, nio

I am running this code to walk a directory -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

public class FindDirectoriesTest {
  public void find()
    throws IOException
  {
    Path dir = Paths.get("some_dir");
    Files.walkFileTree(dir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
          throws IOException
        {
          if (attrs.isDirectory()) {
            //do something;
          } else {
            //do something else
          }
          return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException
        {
          return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

The problem is that `attrs.isDirectory()` doesn't execute even if there is directory. It lists all regular files correctly, but not the directories. Is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 4):

bskaggs is right. I faced the same problem while studying nio package.
Then found this page. Wondering why this question is not answered or closed since it was asked years back.
Here is the code to print sub-directory list of the path you give.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class WalkTreeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users");
        Files.walkFileTree(p, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
        {            
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            if(Files.isDirectory(dir))
                    System.out.println(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }                      
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`visitFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html#visitFile%28T,%20java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes%29) is only called when visiting files, not directories.  You should instead add another function that overrides [`preVisitDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html#preVisitDirectory%28T,%20java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes%29) or [`postVisitDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html#postVisitDirectory%28T,%20java.io.IOException%29) (depending on whether you want the operation to happen before you visit all the files in the sub-directory or after), and place the directory-specific logic there.